# How can emacs org-mode execute shell code remotely as sudo?

Tags: org-mode, org-babel, tramp

My self-documenting maintainance scripts, where I document how systems have been setup, I need to execute stuff as sudo/root and want the results automatically added to the document. But for safety reasons on the target system root has login disabled. I have to connect via an admin-user, which then can sudo stuff.

in my emacs init.el this adds bash execution:

```
;; allow org mode bash execution
;; --------------------------------------
(org-babel-do-load-languages 'org-babel-load-languages '( (shell . t ) ) )
```

Then in my document I have e.g. this bash / shell piece:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC bash :dir /sudo:adminuser@fresh_installed_computer:~/ :results output 
parted /dev/sda "unit GiB" "print free"
parted /dev/sda "unit s" "print free"
#+END_SRC
```

The error message is:

Host 'fresh_installed_computer' looks like a remote host, 'sudo' can only use the local host.

See [Org-Mode Manual: 15 Working with Source Code](https://orgmode.org/manual/Working-with-Source-Code.html)

Using Debian Stretch with Emacs 24.5.1 on the local machine, the remote machine is about to become debian buster fresh install.

---

**UPDATE**

When executing

```
#+BEGIN_SRC bash :dir /ssh:adminuser@fresh_installed_computer|sudo:fresh_installed_computer:~/ :results output :session 
echo "user $USER" 
#+END_SRC
```

The status line holds "Opening connection for root@fresh_installed_computer using sudo... \" and then waits forever

Interestingly: when I add the actual IP address like this, it suddenly works as expected:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC bash :dir /ssh:adminuser@fresh_installed_computer|sudo:XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:~/ :results output :session 
echo "user $USER" 
#+END_SRC
#+RESULTS:
: user root
```

ssh to adminuser@fresh_installed_computer and there pinging works, so name resolving is up.

```
ping fresh_installed_computer
```

Any explanation, or do I need to stick with magic number fixed ip adress in my document?

---

**UPDATE 2**

The issue with resolving hostname vs IP adress
could be solved by *clearing tramp proxy caches*:

```
M-x tramp-cleanup-all-connections
M-: (setq tramp-default-proxies-alist nil)
```

Now all works fine! Thx

Comment: Welcome to emacs stack exchange! Please add emacs version and org-mode version to your question for troubleshooting.

Comment: Does `:dir /ssh:adminuser@fresh_installed_computer|sudo:localhost:~/` or `:dir /ssh:adminuser@fresh_installed_computer|sudo:root@fresh_installed_computer:~/` work instead?

Comment: It could be that tramp is waiting for a prompt. Does `:dir /sshx:adminuser@fresh_installed_computer|sudo:fresh_installed_computer:~/` work? Note the extra `x` in `sshx`.

Comment: Don't use `...|sudo:localhost:` -- that's once again going to create a dangerous proxy on Emacs versions < 27.

Comment: I'm not sure why one of those approaches worked and the other didn't, but you might try `M-x tramp-cleanup-all-connections` and `M-: (setq tramp-default-proxies-alist nil)` and see whether that changes anything?  (Mostly I'm wondering whether earlier attempts had left a dodgy proxy in place, such that it was trying to proxy `root@fresh_installed_computer` to somewhere else.)

Comment: @phils M-x tramp-cleanup-all-connections and 'M-: (setq tramp-default-proxies-alist nil)' actually made it accept hostnames again! thx

Comment: Glad to hear that did the trick.  You should make sure you don't have any lingering instances of bad multi-hop sudo syntax remaining to potentially re-introduce that issue.  Any instance of `...|sudo::` or `...|sudo:localhost:` or any case where you have the likes of `ssh:<foo>|sudo:<bar>:` instead of `ssh:<foo>|sudo:<foo>:` should be fixed, so that the sudo host is the same as the host for the preceding hop.

Comment: Actually with this now working properly, I am *quite* astonished how faar emacs and org mode can be used to integrate my administration and documentation work. I wonder, if my usecase here is something broadly spread or if I am dancing on the edge of freakdom - are there are some documents giving best practices guides, as the comments here show there are traps and no-goes to avoid.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Use `TRAMP` [multi-hop](https://www.gnu.org/software/tramp/#Ad_002dhoc-multi_002dhops) syntax for `:dir` header.

> **4.4 Combining ssh or plink with su or sudo**
>
> If the su or sudo option shall be performed on another host, it could be comnbined with a leading ssh or plink option. That means, TRAMP connects first to the other host with non-administrative credentials, and changes to administrative credentials on that host afterwards. In a simple case, the syntax looks like [`/ssh:user@host|sudo:host:/path/to/file`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2177687/open-file-via-ssh-and-sudo-with-emacs/16408592#16408592).

```
:dir /ssh:user@fresh_installed_computer|sudo:adminuser@fresh_installed_computer:~/
```

> **Tip:** Adding `:session` header to code block can be helpful too.

```
#+BEGIN_SRC bash :dir /ssh:user@fresh_installed_computer|sudo:adminuser@fresh_installed_computer:~/ :results output :session 
parted /dev/sda "unit GiB" "print free"
parted /dev/sda "unit s" "print free"
#+END_SRC
```

---

> **Note:** If the goal is to login as `adminuser` and then sudo to `root` user the tramp connection string would be updated this way instead.
>
> `:dir /ssh:adminuser@fresh_installed_computer|sudo:fresh_installed_computer:~/`
>
> ```
> #+BEGIN_SRC bash :dir /ssh:adminuser@fresh_installed_computer|sudo:fresh_installed_computer:~/ :results > output :session 
> parted /dev/sda "unit GiB" "print free"
> parted /dev/sda "unit s" "print free"
> #+END_SRC
> ```
>
> Thanks to NickD for pointing this out!
>
> ---
>
> **Don't use `...|sudo:localhost:`** -- that's once again going to create a dangerous proxy on Emacs versions < 27
>
> Thanks to phils for pointing this out!

Comment: I may be misunderstanding but I think he needs to login to the remote as adminuser and then sudo (to root) over there: `:dir /ssh:adminuser@fresh_installed_computer|sudo::~/`

Comment: Thanks @NickD - Good point! I'll update my answer with your example.

Comment: @NickD Note that `/ssh:user@host|sudo::~/` is wrong/dangerous on all version of Emacs < 27*.  Anyone who uses -- or *might* use -- earlier versions of Emacs should make certain to specify the host in *every* hop when multi-hopping -- including `sudo:host:` instead of `sudo::`.  I've edited this answer accordingly.  Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/16408592 for more information.  (* The version of Tramp in Emacs 27 handles `sudo::` the way you wanted in this scenario.)

Comment: n.b. The Tramp manual you have linked to is for the latest version of Tramp available on GNU ELPA, rather than the version included in the Emacs distribution.  (Emacs 26.3 has Tramp 2.3.4 for instance.)

Comment: @phils: thanks for the correction and the reference. I did not know that.

Comment: @phils - Thanks for comments and edits! Over the years, I've become so used to typing the full user@host in my tramp sudo hops I completely forgot the reason why I started doing it! I added url into answer as reminder.

Comment: it seems not working: when executing status line #+BEGIN_SRC bash :dir /ssh:adminuser@fresh_installed_computer|sudo:fresh_installed_computer:~/ :results output :session echo "user $USER" #+END_SRC says "Opening connection for root@fresh_installed_computer using sudo... \" and then waits forever

Comment: interestingly: when I use this line and add the ip of the remote computer, it suddenly works as expected:

#+BEGIN_SRC bash :dir /ssh:adminuser@fresh_installed_computer|sudo:XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:~/ :results output :session echo "user $USER" #+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
: user root

I will add this to my question. Maybe you can help me understanding this?